# Automating a Delphi 2007 application with a Python script - how do I unambiguously reference controls?

Tags: python, delphi, ui-automation, pywinauto, delphi-2007

I have a legacy Delphi application that I need to automate for testing purposes.  I'm having difficulty with directing the automation requests to the correct component.  The included example demonstrates the issue (on my environment anyway).  Heres a simple Delphi application I'm wanting to control:

**Project1.dpr**

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button5: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure ControlClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ControlClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.Add (Format ('Control "%s" clicked', [TControl (Sender).Name])) ;
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Assigned(Screen.ActiveControl) then
    begin
    Panel1.Caption := Screen.ActiveControl.Name ;
    end
else
    begin
    Panel1.Caption := 'None.' ;
    end ;
end ;

end.
```

**Unit1.dfm**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 212
  ClientWidth = 407
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 73
    Top = 193
    Width = 32
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Focus:'
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 24
    Top = 8
    Width = 201
    Height = 177
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 304
    Top = 11
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = '1'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
    Left = 296
    Top = 171
    Width = 97
    Height = 17
    Caption = 'CheckBox1'
    TabOrder = 6
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 304
    Top = 42
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = '2'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Left = 304
    Top = 73
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = '3'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object Button4: TButton
    Left = 304
    Top = 104
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = '4'
    TabOrder = 4
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object Button5: TButton
    Left = 304
    Top = 135
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = '5'
    TabOrder = 5
    OnClick = ControlClick
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 116
    Top = 191
    Width = 109
    Height = 17
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Interval = 300
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 240
    Top = 152
  end
end
```

**Automate.py**

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import application

def Click (AForm, AControlName):
    FControl = AForm [AControlName]
    FControl.click()
    return ()

FormTitle = "Form1"
try:
    app = application.Application().connect(title=FormTitle)
    form1 = app[FormTitle]

    Click (form1, "Button1")
    Click (form1, "Button2")
    Click (form1, "Button3")
    Click (form1, "Button4")
    Click (form1, "Button5")

    Click (form1, "Checkbox1")

    exit (0)

except pywinauto.application.ProcessNotFoundError:
    print(f"No running instance of {FormTitle} found.")
    exit (1)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    exit (1)
```

All is good, except that the buttons are reversed.  If I direct a click to Button1, Button5 registers a click.  Other experiments have shown that it's not necessarily predictable as to how it is going to redirect the request - the checkbox is OK for example, though I never tried a larger number of those.  All I want is an unambiguous way of referencing a control - because the control name doesn't cut it.

**UPDATE**
Further experiments have seemed to indicate that the control's *caption* is what I need to pass to the call to send a click message to the control.

Answer (score 0):

Access by attribute or by item performs a typo resistant search procedure. The indexing in this procedure is different. This is described in more details in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

For search by exact caption you need to make search criteria this way (it works faster!):

```
form1.child_window(title="1", class_name="TButton").click()
form1.child_window(title="2", class_name="TButton").click()    
form1.child_window(title="3", class_name="TButton").click()
```

If you want to know the correct specification, just dump it:

```
form1.dump_tree()
```

So you can copy-paste such `child_window` specifications from this dump.

BTW, there is a known issue with `connect` method that requires explicit timeout for now: `connect(title=FormTitle, timeout=10)`